# get Dictionaries Value from Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

this surely is a pretty basic question, but i've been struggling and still no answer.

I have an array of dictionaries, each NSdictionary has the same amount and type of key-value pairs,  i want to store all the values(NSstring) of a given key (all dictionaries have that same key) but still no luck.

the last thing i come up with was:

```
int i=0;
while (i< dictArray.count) {
            [newArray addObject:[dictArray[i] objectForKey:@"keyName"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[dictArray[i] objectForKey:@"keyName"]);
        NSLog(@"%@",newArray);
        i++;
    }
```

In the NSlogs i put for debugging, i can see that [rows[i] objectForKey:@"keyName"] displays te correct NSstring value for "keyName", but the Newarray NSlog shows null, what am i doing wrong? is there a better way to get this valúes? thank you!

PD: newArray is a NSMutaleArray

Comment: U have tocreate an array with the values in the dictionary according to the key values?, U should use value for key

Comment: Have initialized newArray as a nsmutablearray? newArray =[NSMUtableArray array];?

Comment: yes, newArrray is a NSMutableArray

Comment: is it allocated and initialized? newArray =[NSMUtableArray array];?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider the newArray is a Mutable Array. You can do that :

```
 [dictArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
             [newArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"keyName"]];
        }];
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far. +1 :)

Comment: I may be looking wrong...but it isn't a ] missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array which has dictionaries..

```
//Initialze the array
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//For Loop
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in dictArray) {
[newArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"keyName"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `newArray` is `NSMutableArray` object. Did you allocate the `newArray` before the `while` loop? If no, please do this before the loop

```
newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

you will be okay.

Comment: i've got my newArray initialized as a NSMutableArray since is a property of my class

Comment: So you have put the exact line somewhere before the loop starts right?

Comment: i thought that, as a property, the NSMutableArray was allocated and initialized, i see my mistake now, thank you!